# Generating arrays in vuex

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I started learning vuex a week ago and I tried to generate something that look like that:

```
[
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 2 },
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 3 },
]
```

I used the *Array()* constructor to create an empty array of size 3 then tried to fill it using both forEach and *Array.fill()* but when i try to change any element inside the object the crossponding elements inside the array also changes and the value of *cellID* is set to the last value assigned to any other *cellID*.

example:

```
arr[0][0] = true
[
  { isClicked: true, toPlayer: null, cellID: 3 },
  { isClicked: true, toPlayer: null, cellID: 3 },
  { isClicked: true, toPlayer: null, cellID: 3 },
]
```

- I tried hardcoding the array and it worked just fine.
- So how can I generate such an array? and what is causing this to
  happen?

Code for generation:

```
const createGameBoard = () => {
  let row = Array(3);
  const cellDS = {
    isClcicked: false,
    toPlayer: null,
    cellID: null,
  };
  row.fill(cellDS)
  let gameBoard = Array(3)
  gameBoard.fill(row)
  return gameBoard
};
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried. `arr[0].isClicked = true` is probably more what you want.

Comment: @ceejayoz I did try that :"D same problem.

Comment: So show us *how* you tried `Array.fill` and `forEach`. Obviously, what you want to do is possible. Be sure to read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays too.

Comment: @ceejayoz just added it

Comment: Show the code relevant to `"when i try to change any element inside the object the crossponding elements inside the array also changes and the value of cellID is set to the last value assigned to any other cellID"`